# jquery toggling all the content

Tags: jquery, toggle

Hi I'm trying to toggle content sepratly.

For example: if I click on the first content it opens up and the rest stays closed and if I click on the second content the first content closes and the second one opens and it goes on like that until I don't have any more content.

My problem is that when I click on the "+" it opens all the content.

here is my html

```
<div class="description">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut diam lacus, auctor vitae urna eget, sollicitudin ullamcorper eros. Ut mattis dignissim tellus, ac scelerisque turpis fermentum vel. Etiam faucibus eros adipiscing turpis commodo, quis pulvinar ligula ultrices. Suspendisse non felis in nisl mollis tristique vitae vitae turpis. Nunc eleifend fringilla lectus ut dapibus. Aenean et dui sed libero gravida vulputate. Proin eu metus sollicitudin, laoreet mi in, cursus metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed euismod lacus in metus porta, vitae laoreet justo eleifend. Curabitur urna tortor, egestas in dictum vel, dapibus vel orci. In sed ultricies arcu. Vivamus semper eu quam ut faucibus. </p>
</div>
<a href="#" class="toggle-link">+</a>

<div class="description">
<p>Duis bibendum diam ut imperdiet pharetra. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean hendrerit metus et imperdiet consequat. Suspendisse sit amet turpis pellentesque, rutrum tellus vitae, pretium risus. Nunc at mauris nec sem vestibulum dapibus ac eget elit. Cras luctus felis in nibh elementum, ut hendrerit est sagittis. Phasellus quis dolor malesuada, feugiat erat ac, consectetur nisl. Sed auctor dapibus augue, in sagittis ligula congue sed. Curabitur sollicitudin, tortor in scelerisque hendrerit, sem nunc aliquet mi, et accumsan felis dui sit amet erat. Sed fermentum tempus est sit amet malesuada. Donec posuere dui nibh, a ullamcorper nibh interdum sit amet. Maecenas hendrerit in arcu at consequat. Integer tempus dolor at ante ullamcorper sodales. Praesent ultricies turpis id arcu pulvinar, id fringilla metus imperdiet. Etiam felis justo, ultrices a rutrum a, bibendum at dolor. Nam felis nisi, tincidunt fermentum ornare ut, euismod sed felis. </p>
</div>
<a href="#" class="toggle-link">+</a>
```

Here is my Jquery

```
$.fn.toggleClick=function(){
    var functions=arguments;
    return this.click(function(){
        var iteration=$(this).data('iteration')||0;
        functions[iteration].apply(this,arguments);
        iteration= (iteration+1) %functions.length;
        $(this).data('iteration',iteration);
    });
};


var $dscr = $('.description'),
    $switch = $('.toggle-link'),
    initHeight = 40; // Initial height

$dscr.each(function () {
    $(this).data("realHeight", $(this).height()); // Create new property realHeight
}).css({
    overflow: "hidden",
    height: initHeight  
});

$switch.toggleClick(function () {
    $dscr.animate({
        height: $dscr.data("realHeight")
    }, 600);
    $switch.html("-");

}, function () {
    $dscr.animate({
        height: initHeight
    }, 600);
    $switch.html("+");
});
```

Here is the link to the jsfiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cerberus478/hku2N/)

Comment: Is it not exactly what accordion do ? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: yes it is like the accordion, but I need it the way it is in the jsfiddle

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? You do know you can download specific "parts" of jQueryUI if you don't want the whole library, right? You can even change the HTML assignments if you don't want to stay in their `<div[wrapper]><h3><div>` pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this part of your code:

```
$switch.toggleClick(function () {
    $('.description').animate({
        height: 40
    });
    $(this).prevAll('.description:first').animate({
        height: $dscr.data("realHeight")
    }, 600);
    $(this).html("-");

}, function () {
    $dscr.animate({
        height: initHeight
    }, 600);
    $switch.html("+");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hku2N/2/)

You want to use `$(this)` to select the currently clicked element.

Comment: Thank you that worked, I just would like to know about the .prevAll

Comment: It selects the (`:first`) previous element with class `description` ;)