# Creating an accordion type content

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm trying to create something close to the jquery accordian. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

where the first box is open and when you click on the second box the first one closes and the second one opens

So far I've only managed to do this
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5zvdb/)

My html

```
<div class="description">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut diam lacus, auctor vitae urna eget, sollicitudin ullamcorper eros. Ut mattis dignissim tellus, ac scelerisque turpis fermentum vel. Etiam faucibus eros adipiscing turpis commodo, quis pulvinar ligula ultrices. Suspendisse non felis in nisl mollis tristique vitae vitae turpis. Nunc eleifend fringilla lectus ut dapibus. Aenean et dui sed libero gravida vulputate. Proin eu metus sollicitudin, laoreet mi in, cursus metus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed euismod lacus in metus porta, vitae laoreet justo eleifend. Curabitur urna tortor, egestas in dictum vel, dapibus vel orci. In sed ultricies arcu. Vivamus semper eu quam ut faucibus. </p>
</div>
<a href="#" class="toggle-link">+</a>

<div class="description">
<p>Duis bibendum diam ut imperdiet pharetra. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean hendrerit metus et imperdiet consequat. Suspendisse sit amet turpis pellentesque, rutrum tellus vitae, pretium risus. Nunc at mauris nec sem vestibulum dapibus ac eget elit. Cras luctus felis in nibh elementum, ut hendrerit est sagittis. Phasellus quis dolor malesuada, feugiat erat ac, consectetur nisl. Sed auctor dapibus augue, in sagittis ligula congue sed. Curabitur sollicitudin, tortor in scelerisque hendrerit, sem nunc aliquet mi, et accumsan felis dui sit amet erat. Sed fermentum tempus est sit amet malesuada. Donec posuere dui nibh, a ullamcorper nibh interdum sit amet. Maecenas hendrerit in arcu at consequat. Integer tempus dolor at ante ullamcorper sodales. Praesent ultricies turpis id arcu pulvinar, id fringilla metus imperdiet. Etiam felis justo, ultrices a rutrum a, bibendum at dolor. Nam felis nisi, tincidunt fermentum ornare ut, euismod sed felis. </p>
</div>
<a href="#" class="toggle-link">+</a>
```

my jquery

```
$.fn.toggleClick=function(){
    var functions=arguments;
    return this.click(function(){
        var iteration=$(this).data('iteration')||0;
        functions[iteration].apply(this,arguments);
        iteration= (iteration+1) %functions.length;
        $(this).data('iteration',iteration);
    });
};


var $dscr = $('.description'),
    $switch = $('.toggle-link'),
    initHeight = 40; // Initial height

$dscr.each(function () {
    $(this).data("realHeight", $(this).height()); // Create new property realHeight
}).css({
    overflow: "hidden",
    height: initHeight  
});

$switch.toggleClick(function () {
    $(this).prevAll('.description:first').animate({
        height: $dscr.data("realHeight")
    }, 600);
    $(this).html("-");

}, function () {
    $dscr.animate({
        height: initHeight
    }, 600);
    $switch.html("+");
});
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848573/jquery-toggling-all-the-content?noredirect=1#comment33072814_21848573

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel? You do know you can download specific "parts" of jQueryUI if you don't want the whole library, right?

Comment: Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/dYUk5/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Le sigh. I don't know why you're reinventing the wheel or trying to reincorporate the toggle "click" method, but you're far overthinking things. It's this easy:

## *jsFiddle*

```
var initHeight = 40; // Initial height

$('.description')
.each(function(e) { $(this).data("realHeight", $(this).height()); })
.css({ height: initHeight, overflow: 'hidden' });

$('.toggle-link').on('click', function(e) {
    var $desc = $(this).prev();
    if ($desc.hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).text('+');
        $desc.removeClass('open').animate({ height: initHeight }, 600)
    }
    else {
        $(this).text('-');
        $desc.addClass('open').animate({ height: $desc.data('realHeight') }, 600)
        .siblings('.open').removeClass('open')
        .animate({ height: initHeight }, 600, function(e) { $(this).next().text('+'); });
    }
});
```